# Add top padding to font awesome icons

Tags: css, font-awesome

I'm trying to add some top padding only to the font awesome icon, but if I set `padding-top:10px` or `margin-top:10px` to the `i` element, it also adds padding to the text before it.

Can someone help?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pr89yq7n/)

```css
i {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
.block {
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  max-width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}
.block-number {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-number">2 to 4</div>
  <i class="fa fa-large fa-camera-retro"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's possible to do it with other method, but what I would do in your case is positioning the icon absolutely.

```css
i {
  font-size:30px;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.block {
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  padding:10px;
  max-width:400px;
  text-align:center;
  position: relative;
}

.block-number {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-number">
    2 to 4
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-large fa-camera-retro"></i>
</div>
```

I didn't get your answer yet, but if you just want to center the text and icon vertically, use following code:

```css
i {
  font-size:30px;
}

.block {
  background-color:#f1f1f1;
  padding:10px;
  max-width:400px;
  text-align:center;
}

.block-number {
  background-color:#000;
  color:#fff;
  padding:10px;
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:20px;
}

.block > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="block">
  <div class="block-number">
    2 to 4
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-large fa-camera-retro"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Please see the revised jsfiddle. I need to make sure all other styles remain intact.

Comment: But what exactly do you want to achieve? You want to center vertically the text and icon?

Answer (score 4):

Since both of `.block-number` and font awesome `<i>` elements are set to  inline block, so `vertical-align` will take effects, you can change the default value from `baseline` to `top` etc.

```
.block-number, i {
  ...
  vertical-align: top;
}
i {
  ...
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

There is another way by using `position` and `top` to adjust `<i>` element individually.

```
i {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
```